# Using a Line Decoder (Multiplexer) to set multiple outputs high

Tags: multiplexer, output, decoder, line

When using a 3-to-8 Line Decoder / Multiplexer such as the 74HC238, can I set multiple outputs (1-8) as high at the same time?

As opposed to only one output high at any given time, and the rest are low.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. The purpose of a 3-to-8 decoder is to select only a single option. If you require more complex decoding then use a PLD or memory chip instead.